# How to JUnit test for object immutabily?

Tags: java, junit

I have a method similar to this

```
public void method(final Object A){ .... }
```

now I want to write a test which ensures Object A is always final. How do I write such test ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... it is final; it is marked as such.  Are you wanting to test that its value never changes during the execution of `method`?

Comment: basically I don't want the Object A to be changed within this Method. So I want to prevent other developers to come and change the 'final' type of the Object. I want a unit test to guard against such shenanigans.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm afraid you do not understand what your method does. A final parameter in a method means only that the parameter cannot be reassigned in the method.

```
 public void doStuff( String s ){
     s = "OK";
 }
```

but

```
 public void doStuff( final String s ){
     s = "ERROR s cannot be assigned because it is final!";//causes error
 }
```

As such, there is no behaviour that can test for. If it is not valid it will not compile.

---

Edit: If you want you unit test for a final I don't that is possible either since I believe that information is lost at time of compilation once it is checked internally.

Comment: I think it's a perfectly good question - is it possible to unit-test the presence of a `final` method parameter?

Comment: @skaffman I think not since I believe "final" is essentially a compile-time annotation

Comment: Well, I don't have anymore time to spend on this so this is just a pointer not an answer. What you want to do is use reflection to get the parameters for a method (couldn't see how to do this) and check it's modifiers to see if it's final. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#FINAL

Comment: @user381091 Those are modifiers for class members (aka fields) and methods but not for method parameters. You will notice that method parameters also cannot be static, abstract, volatile, transient, etc. If this was an actual _runtime_ annotaiton you could use Method.getParameterAnnotations() .

Comment: basically I don't want the Object A to be changed within this Method. So I want to prevent other developers to come and change the 'final' type of the Object. I want a unit test to guard against such shenanigans

Comment: @paranoid That is probably a terrible thing to achieve in code. If they have access to the class code, they probably have access to the test case and can change it there as well. I don't think there's a way to enforce programmer behavior in that scenario save that you comment the code appropriately and have reasonable expectations from your team.

Comment: @arpanoid You are looking for something like "const" in C++... and that doesn't exist in Java. What you could do is this: create a subclass of Object (or whatever class you accept as a parameter) and then override any method that would modify the class to call org.junit.Assert.fail( "Attempted to call modifier setXXX()" ). Then pass that in. Or you should look into Mock objects with something like Mockito which lets you specify the contract.